# Xcopy - Invalid number of parameters

Tags: cmd.exe, xcopy

I'm trying to create a bat file that will relocate some ECF Files from a folder to a new folder

I have successfully set up a XCopy bat file for other documents (.doc, .ppt) etc and i've copied the text from the working XCopy bat file and changed the *.doc to *.ecf

```
@ECHO OFF

cd C:\Users\Alex.Newton\Documents\Fixes\ProgramName\Binaries
REM This is will copy over .doc documents
FOR %%f IN (*.ecf) DO XCOPY "C:\Users\Alex.Newton\Documents\Fixes\ProgramName\Binaries" "%%f" "C:\Users\Alex.Newton\Documents\Fixes\ProgramName\"
PAUSE
```

Invalid number of parameters happens 9 Times and that is how many ECF Files there are, so it looks like it's detecting them but won't copy them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Invalid number of parameters

You have:

```
cd C:\Users\Alex.Newton\Documents\Fixes\ProgramName\Binaries
FOR %%f IN (*.ecf) DO XCOPY "C:\Users\Alex.Newton\Documents\Fixes\ProgramName\Binaries" "%%f" "C:\Users\Alex.Newton\Documents\Fixes\ProgramName\"
```

The above `xcopy` command has three arguments:

```
"C:\Users\Alex.Newton\Documents\Fixes\ProgramName\Binaries"
"%%f" 
"C:\Users\Alex.Newton\Documents\Fixes\ProgramName\"
```

The syntax for `xcopy` is:

```
XCOPY source [destination] [options]
```

Your third argument is **not** an option (see [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)).

---

#### Correct way to call xopy

As you are already in the correct directory `C:\Users\Alex.Newton\Documents\Fixes\ProgramName\Binaries` you don't need the first argument.

```
FOR %%f IN (*.ecf) DO XCOPY "%%f" "C:\Users\Alex.Newton\Documents\Fixes\ProgramName\"
```

Or:

```
FOR %%f IN (*.ecf) DO XCOPY "C:\Users\Alex.Newton\Documents\Fixes\ProgramName\Binaries\%%f" "C:\Users\Alex.Newton\Documents\Fixes\ProgramName\"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) - Copy files and/or directory trees to another folder.

Comment: In fact, the first argument is mandatory so you _need_ it; hence, as you are already in the correct directory, you don't need the first argument (source) to be fully qualified... :)